# SQL Server change collation on varchar columns that has a foreign key constraint

Tags: sql-server

Is there any easier way to change the collation on columns with foreign key constraints than manually removing them and adding them back up?

I have tried the disabling of the constraints without luck with the statement:

```
ALTER TABLE PM_Minnekorter NOCHECK CONSTRAINT ALL
```

Is it possible to automate the dropping of the constraints and recreation of them again? or is it any other better solutions?

Comment: are u asking abt changing collation on column ? i.e collation are like SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS  these . or u expecting to drop constraints ?

Comment: I am trying to change the collation on column. i am doing it, but i do get an error on the columns that are varchar/string that has a foreign key constraint.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well we cannot  change collation of column which are referenced.
It is clearly mentioned in this link https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190920.aspx.

As far as automate dropping and creating question is concerned we can do that.

You can see it here. [the code is already exlained and available so giving it]
https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3347/drop-and-recreate-all-foreign-key-constraints-in-sql-server/